# Parse error: unexpected WHEN, expecting SEMICOLON

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to implement this when else statement in VHDL but for some reason, I get this error:

```
Line 48. parse error, unexpected WHEN, expecting SEMICOLON
```

Line 48 is this one: `LED<= "1111001" when count_temp = "0001" else`

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity SOURCE is
    Port (clk_in,RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
          COUNT : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
             AN: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
             LED: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end SOURCE;

architecture Behavioral of SOURCE is

signal count_temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal CLK: std_logic;

component clk_div is
port (clk_in: in std_logic;
        clk_out: out std_logic);
end component;


begin
CL: clk_div port map (clk_in, CLK);

counter: process (CLK,RST,count_temp) 

begin
if (RST = '1')then
count_temp <= "0000";
elsif(rising_edge(CLK))then

    if (count_temp <= "1111") then
    count_temp <= count_temp +1;
    else count_temp <= "0000";
    end if;
end if;
end process;

COUNT <= count_temp;
AN <= "1110";

process(count_temp)

begin

LED<= "1111001" when count_temp = "0001" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "0010" else
        "1111001" when count_temp = "0011" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "0100" else
        "1111001" when count_temp = "0101" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "0110" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "0111" else
        "1111001" when count_temp = "1000" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "1001" else
        "1111001" when count_temp = "1010" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "1011" else
        "1111001" when count_temp = "1100" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "1101" else
        "1111001" when count_temp = "1110" else
        "0100100" when count_temp = "1111" else
        "0100111" when others;
    
end process;
```

Comment: When is only allowed inside a process with VHDL 2008 and later. What VHDL standard are you compiling the file with, and in which tool?

Comment: It's a conditional signal assignment statement, as Tricky says only a sequential statement since revision -2008. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignments, where the equivalent is an if statement and where others is not a valid condition.  Your code is missing an `end` for the architecture statement part. Synopsys package std_logic_arith provides no declarations used here, and IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned should be used in lieu of Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned, able to produce locally static expressions (none here though). The `when others` can be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like perhaps two things:

1. Not sure if you can use conditional signal assignment in a process like you are. Try moving outside process?
   2). Per this page [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/cond_s_a.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ejmoorkan/vhdlref/cond_s_a.html). It looks like some syntax error for how you wrote the else part? Maybe just need `else "0100111"`  (no when others)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you are "not sure" about an answer, I suggest leaving a comment instead. You need 50 reputation before you can post comments.

Comment: When is allowed inside a process with VHDL standard 2008 and later. The page you reference is very old - it is a google snapshot from 2009 that has a "whats new in VHDL 1993 section".